# Multiple Tabbed Areas on Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to have multiple tabbed areas on a page, currently they are working together and when you click a tab on one it affects the other.

You can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/pxpsvoc6/

My html is:

```
<div class="recom-content">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active" rel="overview1">Overview</li>
        <li rel="prices1">Prices</li>
    </ul>
    <!--Close Tabs Menu-->

    <div class="tab_container">

        <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="overview1">Overview</h3>
        <div id="overview1" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Lamborghini</h2>
            <h1>huracan</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Adhuidenter us, consuleretis habunte, Caturideo estiaeq uamdien duconsimum cre ni inc re crurarentiam det nonsus; C. Cen Etrei cae perdiere que ta, coneque ina, Cat, popoenatum actatin sultodi factod norum am iusa dica aturnih iciemnenam aperis. Cion</p>
            <br>
            <a href="#"><div class="buttona">Book Now</div></a>
        </div>

        <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="prices1">Prices</h3>
        <div id="prices1" class="tab_content">
            conetasd
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--Close Tabs Container-->

    </div>
    <!--Close Recom Content-->



        <div class="recom-content">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active" rel="overview2">Overview</li>
        <li rel="prices2">Prices</li>
    </ul>
    <!--Close Tabs Menu-->

    <div class="tab_container">

        <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="overview2">Overview</h3>
        <div id="overview2" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Lamborghini</h2>
            <h1>huracan</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Adhuidenter us, consuleretis habunte, Caturideo estiaeq uamdien duconsimum cre ni inc re crurarentiam det nonsus; C. Cen Etrei cae perdiere que ta, coneque ina, Cat, popoenatum actatin sultodi factod norum am iusa dica aturnih iciemnenam aperis. Cion</p>
            <br>
            <a href="#"><div class="buttona">Book Now</div></a>
        </div>

        <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="prices2">Prices</h3>
        <div id="prices2" class="tab_content">
            conetasd
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--Close Tabs Container-->

    </div>
    <!--Close Recom Content-->
```

My css:

```
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
}

ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 75px;
    width:50%;
    background-color: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    font-family: 'montserratlight';
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:75px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    letter-spacing:1px;

}

ul.tabs li:hover {
    background-color:#525252;
    color: #ffffff;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'montserratregular';
}

.tab_container {
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tab_content {
    padding: 10%;
    display: none;
}

.tab_content h2 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
}

.tab_content hr {
    width:20%;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;

    border:1px solid #dadcdf;
}

.tab_content p:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}


.recom-content  {
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:left;
    border:1px solid #dadcdf;
}


.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .tabs {
        display: none;
    }
    .tab_drawer_heading {

        font-family: 'montserratregular';
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:50px;
        color:#ffffff;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        letter-spacing:0px;
        text-align:center;

        background-color:#b1b8be;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 2px 0px;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom:1px solid #a8afb7;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .d_active {
        background-color:#6f787e;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
// tabbed content
    // http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/tabs.asp
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

  /* if in tab mode */
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();        

      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");

      $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");

    });
    /* if in drawer mode */
    $(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();

      $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");

      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
    });


    /* Extra class "tab_last" 
       to add border to right side
       of last tab */
    $('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you have multiple occurence of the same code. You can't simply use classes, as each occurence have the same classes.

You have to provide a `parent` on which you'll find elements to apply modifications on

```
var parent = $(this).parents(".recom-content");
parent.find(".tab_content").hide();
```

Here is your modified code in a snippet:

```js
// tabbed content
// http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/tabs.asp
$(".recom-content").find(".tab_content").hide();
$(".recom-content").find(".tab_content:first").show();

/* if in tab mode */
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents(".recom-content"),
        activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    
    parent.find(".tab_content").hide();
    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();  
    
    parent.find("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    
    parent.find(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
    parent.find(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");
    
});
/* if in drawer mode */
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {
    var parent = $(this).parents(".recom-content"),
        d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
  
    parent.find(".tab_content").hide();
    $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
    
    parent.find(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
    parent.find(this).addClass("d_active");
    
    parent.find("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    parent.find("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
});

/* Extra class "tab_last" 
to add border to right side
of last tab */
$('.recom-content').find('ul.tabs li:last').addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
ul.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom:10%;
}

ul.tabs li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 75px;
 width:50%;
 background-color: #000000;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;

 font-family: 'montserratlight';
 font-size:15px;
 line-height:75px;
 color:#ffffff;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 text-align:center;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 letter-spacing:1px;

}

ul.tabs li:hover {
 background-color:#525252;
 color: #ffffff;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
 background-color:#ffffff;
 color: #000000;
 display: block;
 font-family: 'montserratregular';
}

.tab_container {
 border-top: none;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 400px;
 background-color:#ffffff;
 overflow: auto;
}

.tab_content {
 padding: 10%;
 display: none;
}

.tab_content h2 {
 text-transform:uppercase;
 letter-spacing:3px;
 margin-bottom:4px;
}

.tab_content hr {
 width:20%;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-bottom:20px;

 border:1px solid #dadcdf;
}

.tab_content p:last-of-type {
 margin-bottom:0px;
}


.recom-content {
 width:200px;
 height:auto;
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:top;
 text-align:left;
 border:1px solid #dadcdf;
}


.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .tabs {
  display: none;
 }
 .tab_drawer_heading {

  font-family: 'montserratregular';
  font-size:13px;
  line-height:50px;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  letter-spacing:0px;
  text-align:center;

  background-color:#b1b8be;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom:1px solid #a8afb7;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
 }
 .d_active {
  background-color:#6f787e;
  color: #fff;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="recom-content">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active" rel="overview1">Overview 1</li>
        <li rel="prices1">Prices 1</li>
    </ul>
    <!--Close Tabs Menu-->
    
    <div class="tab_container">
        
        <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="overview1">Overview</h3>
        <div id="overview1" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Lamborghini</h2>
            <h1>huracan</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Adhuidenter us, consuleretis habunte, Caturideo estiaeq uamdien duconsimum cre ni inc re crurarentiam det nonsus; C. Cen Etrei cae perdiere que ta, coneque ina, Cat, popoenatum actatin sultodi factod norum am iusa dica aturnih iciemnenam aperis. Cion</p>
            <br>
            <a href="#"><div class="buttona">Book Now</div></a>
        </div>
        
        <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="prices1">Prices</h3>
        <div id="prices1" class="tab_content">
            conetasd
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <!--Close Tabs Container-->
    
</div>
<!--Close Recom Content-->



<div class="recom-content">
    
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="active" rel="overview2">Overview 2</li>
        <li rel="prices2">Prices 2</li>
    </ul>
    <!--Close Tabs Menu-->
    
    <div class="tab_container">
        
        <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="overview2">Overview</h3>
        <div id="overview2" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Lamborghini</h2>
            <h1>huracan</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Adhuidenter us, consuleretis habunte, Caturideo estiaeq uamdien duconsimum cre ni inc re crurarentiam det nonsus; C. Cen Etrei cae perdiere que ta, coneque ina, Cat, popoenatum actatin sultodi factod norum am iusa dica aturnih iciemnenam aperis. Cion</p>
            <br>
            <a href="#"><div class="buttona">Book Now</div></a>
        </div>
        
        <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="prices2">Prices</h3>
        <div id="prices2" class="tab_content">
            conetasd
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <!--Close Tabs Container-->
    
</div>
<!--Close Recom Content-->
```

Comment: this works great! when I just have them as static boxes. I am trying to create this within a slider which seems to be not working.. You can see it here: http://pagedev.co.uk/iselfdrive2/about.php I would have thought that it would still work?

Comment: If the structure is the same as provided, it should work no matter you are in a slider or not. Did you try to empty your cache after the update on your site?

Comment: I cleared my cache. Its working ok until you click on the second slides tabs, it knocks out the layout and then the tabs stop loading content. If you look at the link in my comment above, hopefully it creates the same issue for you? Any help would be great! Stressing!

Comment: I have worked out that its only when the last tab is clicked that the error occurs.. If I add another slide between those two it then becomes that the 3rd slide only creates the issue

Comment: May be an issue with `$('.recom-content ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");`. Replace it by `$('.recom-content').find('ul.tabs li:last').addClass("tab_last");`

Comment: I'll edit my snippet to add the change from my last comment. Should work better !

Comment: Hi mate, worked it out. It didn't like the vertical slide. Fade makes it work fine! Thanks for all your help1

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the statement that hides:

```
$(".tab_content").hide();
```

to

```
$(this).parents(".recom-content").find(".tab_content").hide();
```

Your selector is hiding *all* of the tab_content items, and it should only hide the ones that are descendants of its parent recom-content DIV.

Comment: this works great! when I just have them as static boxes. I am trying to create this within a slider which seems to be not working.. You can see it here: pagedev.co.uk/iselfdrive2/about.php I would have thought that it would still work?